# math confirmation for average of tax charged on two combined records

Tags: .net, vb.net, math

I am not sure of my math and am looking for confirmation.

I want to take two records in a database and combine their values into one average value and save that value in another table.  I have no trouble with the db operations.  I just need to make sure my math is right.

Note, the tax rate is stored as a decimal value in SQL server so 5.5% is stored as 5.50 (double type)

### For example:

```
Record         Quantity         Unit Cost         Tax Rate    
Record 1:        10             $10.00              5%    
Record 2:        10             $10.00             10%
```

### What I am currently doing:

I combine the total combined value for each record (unit cost * quatity) together

(10*$10.00) + (10*$10.00) = $200

Then I get the total amount including tax

(100*1.05) + (100*1.1) = $215

Then I divide the total tax included amount by the total value

215 / 200 = 1.075

I take off the 1 and then multiply by 100 to get the whole tax rate like

(1.075 - 1) * 100 = 7.5%

all together:

```
NewAveragedTaxRate = (((((Quanity1 * Unit1) * (tax1 / 100 + 1)) + ((Quanity2 * Unit2) * (tax2 / 100 + 1))) / ((Quanity1 * Unit1) + (Quanity2 * Unit2))) -1) * 100
```

So I think my tax rate is 7.5%

### Question:

1. Is this right, the equasion works, but is this the right way to average tax/percent?
2. Secondly, is there a way I can simplify this, I feel like I am overcomplicating it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the final two equations are overkill. Just do (GrandTotal - GrossTotal) / GrossTotal. In this example, (215 - 200) / 200 = 0.075 = 7.5%.

Comment: thanks, just needed an outside perspective to confirm.